The problem I have met when I installed the TeX Live--"Failed to install doclicense"
"TLPDB::_install_data: untar failed for G:/archive/doclicense.r68441.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install doclicense
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]"
This is the information, I can't find the correct methods to solve it.May I install it again?Maybe the process is a little trouble.
